# PDO select and count IN HAVING DISTINCT to appear in dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have this mysql select working great. It returns the proper data. I can't seem to get the context correct to place the actual count of the custnum so it will appear on the end of the dropdown option select.
     This statement returns the proper location names

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT locationname FROM location WHERE locationname IN (SELECT locationname FROM location_user WHERE custnum= :custnum GROUP BY locationname HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT email) < 6 )");
  $statement->execute(array(':custnum' => $session->custnum));

 while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo'<option value="'.$row['locationname'].'">'.$row['locationname'].'('. $row['COUNT(total)'] .')</option>';    
}
```

Here's one of my attempts to grab the total for each custnum

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT locationname, COUNT(custnum) AS total FROM location WHERE  locationname IN (SELECT locationname FROM location_user WHERE custnum= :custnum GROUP BY locationname HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT email) < 6 )");
$statement->execute(array(':custnum' => $session->custnum));

while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo'<option value="'.$row['locationname'].'">'.$row['locationname'].'('. $row['total'] .')</option>';    
}
```

Here's my tables

```
       table location                            table location_user
custnum   |   locationname             custnum   |    locationname  |   email    |  userlevel
   1           location1                 1            location1       1me@you.com       3
   1           location2                 1            location1       1me@you.com       1
                                         1            location1       2me@you.com       2
                                         1            location1       3me@you.com       2
                                         1            location1       4me@you.com       2
                                         1            location1       5me@you.com       2
                                         1            location2       1me@you.com       2
                                         1            location2       1me@you.com       3
```

The first select returns

```
 location1()
 location2()
```

The second select returns

```
 location1(2)
```

I actually need the count of the distinct email which the query is doing and returning only the locationnames of the distinct email in the table less then 6 but how do I get the actual number of distinct emails for each locationname.

This select will retrieve the total for DISTINCT email, but how do I combine the two into one for my while loop?

```
$statement2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(email) AS total FROM location_user WHERE custnum= :custnum GROUP BY locationname HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT email) < 6");
$statement2->execute(array(':custnum' => $session->custnum));
```

Here's the working version from the help of Peter and a little prodding from Tin.

```
 $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT l.locationname, COUNT(DISTINCT lu.email) AS total 
 FROM location l LEFT JOIN location_user lu ON l.locationname = lu.locationname AND l.custnum = lu.custnum WHERE l.custnum = :custnum GROUP BY l.locationname HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT lu.email)  < 5 ");
 $statement->execute(array(':custnum' => $session->custnum));

 while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 echo'<option value="'.$row['locationname'].'">'.$row['locationname'].'('. $row['total'] .')</option>';    
 }
```

Here's another version that I'm working on to skip the user that adds the locations to the table. This user will always have a userlevel > 2. The uselevel is placed in the location_user table only as a value between 1-9. So I still need the location name but I don't want their location included in the count. I just realized that I could actually go a better route because the only email that I want to count will have a userlevel of 2. I was using the distinct email to filter out the userlevel of 1. I'll give it a go. The below version drops my locations that arn't in the location_user table but it's returning the proper count.

```
     SELECT l.locationname, COUNT(lu.userlevel) AS total 
     FROM location l LEFT JOIN location_user lu
     ON l.locationname = lu.locationname
     AND l.custnum = lu.custnum
     WHERE l.custnum = :custnum
     AND lu.userlevel = 2
     GROUP BY l.locationname
     HAVING COUNT(lu.userlevel) < 6
```

Comment: Can you show table schemas and sample data?

Comment: I added the table info and a select that will retrieve the total emails but I can't figure out how to combine into one statement for the while loop.

Comment: Can you show the **exact** desired output based on the sample data? Your explanation is unclear.

Comment: The desired output from the posted table data would be location1(5) and location2(1) Because it treats the two 1me@you.com emails in location1 as one.

Comment: Thanks Peterm, I think that will do it. I was getting close. Those joins are looking a little more familiar. Thanks for all your time and expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE2:** based on your comments. Try it this way

```sql
SELECT l.locationname, COUNT(DISTINCT lu.email) AS total 
  FROM location l LEFT JOIN location_user lu
    ON l.locationname = lu.locationname
   AND l.custnum = lu.custnum
   AND lu.userlevel < 3 -- consider only users with user level < 3
 WHERE l.custnum = ?
 GROUP BY l.locationname 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT lu.email) < 6
```

Sample output:

```
| LOCATIONNAME | TOTAL |
|--------------|-------|
|    location1 |     5 |
|    location2 |     1 |
|    location3 |     0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e1c3/2)** demo

Comment: This would be fine but I need for it to pull those locationname's available from the location table if they haven't been added to the location_user table. That's why I was using the IN select.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have solved my problem. I so struggle with those join statements that get that involved. It appears to be doing exactly what I was looking for. I get the strings and how many of each and it removes them if there's 6 so their not available to choose. Totally awesome. Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit your code a little to work with my pdo variable bind.

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally forgot that I have a user that is adding locations to the table and I want them skipped from the email count. It could be based on userlevel as I have that value in the location_user. I would like to skip counting the emails if the userlevel is > 2 . I'm not sure where to append the code but will take a shot at it looking at yours and post it above.

Comment: Please see updated answer and sqlfiddle example. This particular condition should be in `ON` clause  when the `OUTER JOIN` is used. Meaning you want to filter rows on the right side of the `LEFT JOIN` before you join them.

Answer (score 0):

you don't actually need to query from table `location` since you already have `locationname` field from table `location_user`

```
SELECT locationname, count(DISTINCT email) as total FROM location_user WHERE custnum = :custnum GROUP BY locationname HAVING count(DISTINCT email) < 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both tables have the custnum but I just realized that the last version is returning the proper values but it's not what I want.  The first select as of right now returns two strings in the drop down but no total. The second one returns one string with the number two in for the total. So I think it's returning the total number of locations which is two. I might need to tweak my tables.

Comment: in that case, i think you need to GROUP BY locationname at the end of the query and you'll get two strings in the drop down again.

Comment: I tried the above select with the INNER JOIN and it returns the same result as my second select posted above.

Comment: Ok I need to look at my code again. I added a another locationname to the location table and I didn't get the results I thought I would. I thought I had it working correctly so the select would only show location names from the location table that were in the location_user table less then 6 times.

Comment: see the other answer by peterm, he's got it!